# Aura Lightning Components - waiting for event or cmp.find('editForm').submit() to finish

Tags: lightning, aura, event, lightning-recordeditform

I need to clone an item that contains lightning:recordEditForm before the user clicks submit and values are saved. The problem is that before my cloning I need to force recordEditForm to save. I looked through google but can't find answer:

Is there way to wait for cmp.find('editForm').submit() to execute?
Or is there any way to wait till event fire() executes?

If I just try to run it normally cmp.find('editForm').submit() executes too slow and I don't have proper values in cloned item.
I tested it with setTimeout and it's working but would prefer some other mechanism.

Can I somehow use promise or callback for an event or submit()?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an onsuccess handler to continue.

```
<lightning:recordEditForm onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}" onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}" ... />
```